# How to add tooltip on Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

its me again.

I just want to figure out the problem in my datepicker. i Just wanted to add a tooltip on it. however, the tooltip

I added this code.

```
$("body").tooltip({ selector: '[title]' });
```

and i have this fiddle. Please help.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shandye2/jf6gw9Lh/3/)

Comment: you have error in your fiddle `$(...).datepicker is not a function` the script for this datepicker is not loaded

Comment: I have already added the bootstrap-datepicker.